# How to get correct IServiceProvider instance in my extension method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, extension-methods, .net-8.0

I am writing extension methods for my api to be used in host builder and I need to get an instance of IServiceProvider in it.

I saw that `builder.Services.AddDbContext<T>()`

has a parameter

> (IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder)

, so i tought to just add it to my extension method but how?

Lets say I have this extension method:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceProvider, MyServicesOptionBuilder> overrides)
    {
        ...
        return services;
    }
}
```

and the expected usage is this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddMyServices((serviceProvider, config)=>
{
    var serviceconfiguration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeServiceConfiguration>();
    cfg.ConfigureService1(serviceconfiguration);
    cfg.ConfigureService2(serviceconfiguration);

    ....
});
```

What I don't understand is, who or how is IServiceProvider passed into the Action parameter?

Comment: I don't understand; you say you need to pass `IServiceProvider`, but your method takes `Action<IServiceProvider, MyServicesOptionBuilder>`. Please edit your question to make it clear what you actually **want** to do.

Comment: You don't add services to a host you add services to the ServiceCollection. A Host can provide you with one. Are you sure you want to extend IHostBuilder?

Comment: I can extend IServicesCollection instead of IHostBuilder.  It doesn't matter to me.

Comment: @IanKemp, Yes my method does get IServieProvider, but from where, who des provide it to my method, how?

Comment: What you are trying to achive? As Background you add service to a ServiceCollection and after that configuration you get a read only collection of that as IServiceProvider created from that. You can't add services to the ServiceProvider. If you need to get services from the provider to add your service to the Collection you call an AddXXX overload of the Collection that takes a callback. In that callback that is called after the actual IServiceProvider collection creation for that host you have access to a IServiceProvider you can retrieve dependencies from to setup your service.

Comment: I am trying to create an api that uses  builder pattern to register and configure a variety of services my application will have. I will have maybe 50 services that needs to be registered and correctly configured, and I don't want this complexity to be on the user shoulder. So I want to create an api to facilitate the configuration for the users of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example I created:

```
public record MyServicesOptionBuilder 
{
    public string DependencyName { get; set; }
};
public record MyDependency(string DependencyName);

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceProvider, MyServicesOptionBuilder> overrides)
    {
        // get IServiceProvider from IServiceCollection
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        // create MyServicesOptionBuilder instance
        var options = new MyServicesOptionBuilder();

        // Let the client set option's value
        overrides.Invoke(serviceProvider, options);

        // create MyDependency instance using the option value that was set by the client
        var dependency = new MyDependency(options.DependencyName);

        services.AddKeyedSingleton("Second", dependency);

        serviceProvider.GetKeyedServices<MyDependency>("Second");

        Debug.Assert(dependency.DependencyName == "This is a different dependency");
        Console.WriteLine(dependency.DependencyName);
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton("First" ,new MyDependency("This is a dependency"));

builder.Services.AddMyServices((services, options) =>
{
    var firstDependency = services.GetRequiredKeyedService<MyDependency>("First");

    Debug.Assert(firstDependency.DependencyName == "This is a dependency");
    Console.WriteLine(firstDependency.DependencyName);

    options.DependencyName = "This is a different dependency";
});
```

> What I don't understand is, who or how is IServiceProvider passed into the Action parameter?

As you can see, you are the one who will create the `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Now, When You do services..BuildServiceProvider() , what scope do You get? Because if I have a service registered as singleton, will I get the same instance or I could get different instance for it. I'm asking this because BuildServiceProvider creates new instance of ServiceProvider, and ASP.NET will use it's internal.

Comment: You will receive the same instance. `IServiceProvider` is just an interface for retrieving your registered services from the IoC container. It doesn't matter if you create different instances of IServiceProvider itself. You can easily verify this by calling BuildServiceProvider twice. Then, use these two instances to obtain singletons. Finally, compare the references of the retrieved singletons to see if they are new instances each time.